# CIFilter on SKScene

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skscene, cifilter

I am working on a simple game with Sprite Kit. What I need to do is to apply Black & White filter on the whole scene. This is my code:

```
self.filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
[self.filter setDefaults];
[self.filter setValue:@1 forKey:kEffectKeySaturation];
self.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
```

It works perfect, but the point is that the game gets stuck for a moment and I got this message in log:

BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted

Am I doing something wrong? How to get rid of this message?

Comment: I don't think the message has anything to do with CIFilter. Try not applying the filter to see if the issue goes away, I bet it does not.

Comment: Without applying filter there is no such message

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, for some reason in iOS 8 it is connected with the following line:

```
self.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
```

I experienced it using Swift and found that even blank `SKScene` with no children gives this error after setting this property to `YES`. I suppose the effects are enabled (by software renderer) by default in iOS 8, but it's only a guess.

In my experience, this error caused nasty problem where `SKShader`'s stopped rendering. You can get rid of it by deleting the mentioned line.